# How are ants able to dig with such pointy limbs?

Tags: entomology, bio-mechanics

Digging is usually efficient with somewhat broader structures shovels, no one tries to shovel with an ice-pick. Given that ants have very pointy mandibles and thin wispy legs, how are they able to dig anything? Is it  honestly solely by the means that the granules of soil are somehow coincidentally always the right size to fit in their mandibles?

Comment: Wow nothing after all this time, I didn't think this would be that hard of a question.

Comment: "pointy" is relative term. Try to shovel pieces that are 1m/3ft wide using garden shovel. You look at ant with your eyes, not ant's

Comment: It is a relative term, but that doesn't magically make it any less true. Obviously we are talking pointy relative to a human scale, often able to pierce human skin at terrestrial pressures. If we need additional information about the detail of their body at a finer level of observation, that is still relevant information towards answering the question.

Comment: what have you done to asnwer this quesiton?

Comment: I did research on people who raised ant farms. I was lucky enough to find a video that showed a close up of ants digging in a glass vial and it showed that they were moving artificial granules. However, this is not the same as their natural environment, so I don't actually know of the granules are realistic or if the ants instinctually adapted to the artificial granules. There's plenty of random sites giving vague entries about what ants use digging for, but there is little on the actual mechanics of how they are able to dig in regular dirt in the first place.

Comment: Wow, STILL no answer, maybe a research paper can be written about this since the answer is so pervasive. I've had that happen before, I did research on the mechanisms of ants ability to stick and discovered that their saliva contributed to it over smooth surfaces.